Can not Change width of textField in Java Swing
I am using Dimension(width, height) to manipulate the height and width , but only the height is changing, not the width.
I tried the following -
 cal = new JTextField("0"){
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(200, 40);
    }
   };


try new JTextField("0", 40) - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField-java.lang.String-int-

Before posting here, study the tutorials provided free of cost by Oracle: How to Use Text Fields

Never set the preferred size of a text component for in doing so, you break how the functionality of the component, especially if the text extends past the component's boundaries. As for your problem, set the component's column width as others are telling you, and check out the layout managers and overall layout plan that you are using. Hopefully nothing else is being artificially constrained in size.

Whether the "preferred size" is considered, or not, depends on the layout manager. Maybe you can [edit] your question and post a [mcve]? Also maybe post a screen capture of how your GUI looks and how you want it to look.
